# Paper printable case for Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: case, printing

There is the [punnet paper printable case](http://www.raspberrypi.org/the-punnet-a-card-case-for-you-to-print-for-free/), but it's for the old version of the Raspberry Pi. I have a Raspberry Pi 2, does a similar printable case template exist some place for this model?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was only able to find [this](http://sixes.net/rdcHQ/rdchq-extra-credit-raspi-b/) on Google.  It should work for the RPi 2. It's in a PDF form instead of a nice SVG, but it looks like it could fit what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I made a printbable case for the Rapsberry Pi 3 Model B, if you are interested in this one.
It can be downloaded at the Embedded Linux Wiki [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Cases#Printable_Mylar_Sheet.2Fcardboard_Fold-up_Case). There are also cases for other models if you are not already using the RPi 3.

Comment: not fitting the question